# Computing the Series the looks cute

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do we calculate without residues that , $ \displaystyle \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^6}$ where $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ and $a$ is not an integer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2} = \psi'(a) \tag{1}$$
hence for every $a\not\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2} = \frac{\pi^2\cos(\pi a)}{\sin^2(\pi a)}\tag{2} $$
and your series is clearly related with $\frac{d^4}{da^4}$ applied to the RHS of $(2)$:

> $$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^6} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^6}{960\sin^6(\pi a)}\left(1682\cos(\pi a)+237\cos(3\pi a)+\cos(5\pi a)\right)}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: May I ask what is the reason behind the downvote?